# Degree Major Choice

Tags: untagged

I have about 10 years of experience in IT and a handful of certifications and am planning on going to university and getting a bachelor's degree. My experience has been progressive up to this point but a lot of jobs I'd like to be moving into (be they technical or management) require a degree and I'd also really like to move into management at some point.

I am trying to determine what the best major for me to take is - a computer science degree (be it computer science, computer information systems, or whatever) or a business degree (like a business administration degree with a management information systems concentration or something like that). I'm not sure that either would be especially relevant to my job performance on the technical side of IT so I'm kind of interested in the MIS business major but would hate to have it reflect unfavorably on a job application because it's a 'lighter' degree than CS.

I'd love to hear anyone's viewpoints on this subject and their experiences.

Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: That's horrible advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with programming or infrastructure administration, you pretty much can't go wrong with CS. Depending on the CIS program, it can be just as applicable, but it's learning toward accomplishing management goals.

MIS degrees haven't had the development and honing that CS programs have; so I advise them to people who want to go into Management much more than a technical professional.

Bachelors in Business Admin are a dime a dozen these days; MBA are still highly regarded however, so if you're going the BSBA route, I'd plan on continuing to MBA.

Just my 2 cents of course. Find a good school and their counseling program will know all this too.